# How to find the limit of $\lim_{x\to2}(\sqrt{2x+5}-3)/(x-2)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you be able to simplify the square root of $2x+5$

Comment: Take the conjugate: $\sqrt{2x+5}+3$ and multiply times numerator and denominator...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculus 1: Find the limit as x approaches 4 of $\frac{3-\sqrt{x+5}}{x-4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981332/calculus-1-find-the-limit-as-x-approaches-4-of-frac3-sqrtx5x-4)

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but already 100s of similar questions are present on the site.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} \frac {\sqrt{2x+5} - 3} {x - 2}
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} \frac {\left( \sqrt{2x+5} - 3 \right) \left( \sqrt{2x+5} + 3 \right)} {\left( x - 2 \right) \left( \sqrt{2x+5} + 3 \right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} \frac {2x+5 - 9} {\left( x - 2 \right) \left( \sqrt{2x+5} + 3 \right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} \frac {2x - 4} {\left( x - 2 \right) \left( \sqrt{2x+5} + 3 \right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} \frac {2 \left( x - 2 \right)} {\left( x - 2 \right) \left( \sqrt{2x+5} + 3 \right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} \frac 2 {\sqrt{2x+5} + 3} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 2 {\sqrt{2(2)+5} + 3} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 2 {3 + 3} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 2 6 \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 1 3
\end{array}$$